# UITableView deleting rows, commitEditingStyle method not firing?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a tableView that I want to allow editing and delete rows. I make it go into editing mode fine. But when I press the delete button it's not firing off the event to make it delete the row?

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)editTable:(id)sender {

    if(self.editing) {
        [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
        [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:NO];
        [self.tableView  reloadData];
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
    } else {
        [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [self.tableView  setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [self.tableView  reloadData];
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyleforRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"HIT THIS BABY");
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    [accountsArray removeObjectAtIndex:row];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran this together:

```
editingStyleforRowAtIndexPath
```

It should have been,

```
editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath
```